# How to detect a newline in string input in C++

Tags: c++

I want to count each newline 
If the input like this:

> Hi moon 
> this day I wanna  
> help

Should be the output like this:

> 1 Hi moon
>  2 this day I wanna 
>  3 help

I write this code:

```
int main() {
    string str; int c = 0;
    cin >> str;
    int j = 0;
    string t[200];
    while (str != ";")
    {
        t[j] = str;
        cin >> str;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < j;i++){
    cout << c << " " << t[j];

    if (t[j] == "\n") c++;
}

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and I was to try :

```
int c[100];
    cin >> str;
    int j = 0;
    string t[200];
    while (str != ";")
    {
        string temp;
        t[j] = str;
        temp = t[j];
        if (temp.find("\n"))
            c[j] += 1;
        cin >> str;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < j;i++){
    cout << c[i] << " " << t[j];

}
```

Can anyone tell to me how to detect a newline in string input and print it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read line by line. Put in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Print the vector indexes (plus one) and the strings from the vector.

Comment: How to use std::vector in print?

Comment: @A.be - You already seem to know how to print an array of strings. Now just *guess* how to print a vector of strings!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start by defining what a new line is. On windows, it is a sequence of two characters `\r\n`, on UNIX it is simply `\n`. Treating new line as '\n' will suffice in your case since your dealing with text input (not binary, as C will handle the translation).

I suggest you split your problem into two sub-problems:

1. Store one line
2. Iterate while there are more lines

I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* nextLine(char* input, int* pos) {
  char* temp = new char[200];
  int lpos = 0; // local pos

  while(input[*pos] != '\n') {
    temp[lpos++] = input[(*pos)++];
  }

  temp[*pos] = '\0';

  (*pos)++;

  return temp;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "hello\nworld!\ntrue";
    int pos = 0;

    while(pos < strlen(str)){
        cout << nextLine(str, &pos) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps!